# Adding a check box in ReadyToInstall Dialog in Basic MSI

Tags: windows-installer, installshield-2010

I have added a checkbox to the ReadyToInstall Dialog in Installshield for a basic MSI.
What I want to do is to set a property ISCHECKBOXSELECT to 0 or 1 depending on whether the CheckBox was selected during the installation or not.
0-Not Checked
1-Checked

Do I need to write any custom action for this? When should it be scheduled?

Can anyone pls tell me the steps that I need to perform to achieve this in Basic MSI?
I am using Installshield 2009, 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the values 0 and 1, you will need a custom action. However generally what you really need is false and true values, which for MSI are the empty string and any non-empty string (so "" and "1" are common for checkboxes).

If you can use the latter, all you have to do is add the checkbox in the dialog editor and associate it with your chosen property. Unless you're trying to leverage an existing IS* property, though, I'd strongly recommend choosing a different prefix on the name (e.g. `YOURPROPERTY`), as InstallShield adds its custom variables with an IS prefix.

If you really need the values 0 and 1, you will have to add a set-property custom action that sets `YOURPROPERTY` to `0` if `Not YOURPROPERTY`. I would schedule this in the execute sequence if you need it in the execute sequence, or somewhere near ExecuteAction in the UI sequence if you need it in the UI.